# Sencha GXT 2.3.1 grid header menu no longer displaying properly

Tags: gxt

I've just migrated my Sencha GXT/GWT app to gxt2.3.1 from gxt2.3.0

All good apart from this one problem.  The grid header menu no longer displays properly, as shown in the attached pic.

Anyone else come across this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

FIXED.
Turns out it must have been a change in the resources.

I had copied over .css and images (after I saw this problem) but the old resources must have remained cached somewhere.  On my server I think as I reset my browser cache.

moral of the story, always copy all files over when migrating to a new version of GXT. ;)

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

Check gxt and gwt version in your build path.

For eg : gxt-2.2.3 will suit gwt-2.2.0.

If gwt version is higher than gxt, this kinda problem will come.